# Access custom data-* attributes for a list item that has been stored as an array element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I can't figure out the right syntax to access custom data-* attributes for list elements of an unordered list that has been sorted and then stored as array elements using:

```
$("#gridlist").sortable("toArray");
```

The list elements in the unordered list are generated dynamically by processing array elements like this:

```
<?php  //generate the list items

for ($i=0;$i<$listsize;$i++){
?>
    <li id="griditem_<?php echo $i ?>"
        class="grid-sort-items"
        data-var1="<?php echo $varone[$i] ?>"
        data-var2="<?php echo $vartwo[$i] ?>"
        data-var3="<?php echo $varthree[$i] ?>"
        data-var4="constant1"
        data-var5="constant2">

        <img class="grid-sort-img" src='<?php echo $image-url[$i] ?>'/>
        <span class="grid-sort-title" ><?php echo $image-title[$i] ?></span> 
    </li>
<?php
}
?>
```

So far, so good. The unordered list is created, it displays as it should, and it's sortable.  The custom data-* attributes contain/echo what they should.

After sorting the array, I create a new array with the new order of list elements for further processing before sending to database.

The js to create the new sorted array:

```
    $("#gridlist").sortable({stop: function(event, ui) {
    result = $("#gridlist").sortable("toArray");

    // WHAT I NEED TO DO NOW IS ACCESS A CUSTOM data- ATTRIBUTE OF ANY
    // LIST ITEM STORED IN THE result ARRAY.  I'M NEW TO CUSTOM DATA 
    // ATTRIBUTES AND I CAN'T FIGURE IT OUT :( .  THIS DOESN'T WORK:

    alert(result[0].griditem_0.getAttribute('data-var1'));

    }});
```

I think all I need help with is getting that alert working so I'll understand the syntax.  I have more work to do after that, but once I know how to get at the custom data- attibutes, I think Bob's my uncle.

Comment: Can you include the HTML at Question and create a stacksnippets to demonstrate? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @guest271314 - the relevant php + html to generate the list elements is posted.  What additional html are you looking for?  I'm sorry but I don't have a working snippet - the code has been simplified to make the question clearer.  I guess I could write one from scratch but I'm hoping the question on syntax is obvious to someone first.

Comment: Can you include the generated HTML at the Question and reproduce _"THIS DOESN'T WORK:

    `alert(result[0].griditem_0.getAttribute('data-var1'));`"_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of data attributes is not like that. They are **attributes** not **tags**. I don't know what actually going to do but you can give them to li like below.

```
<?php  //generate the list items

for ($i=0;$i<$listsize;$i++){?>
        <li id="griditem_<?php echo $i ?>"
            class="grid-sort-items"
            data-var1="<?php echo $varone[$i] ?>"
            data-var2="<?php echo $vartwo[$i] ?>"
            data-var3="<?php echo $varthree[$i] ?>"
            data-var4="constant1"
            data-var5="constant2">

            <img class="grid-sort-img" src='<?php echo $image-url[$i] ?>'/>
            <span class="grid-sort-title" ><?php echo $image-title[$i] ?></span> 
        </li>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok, thx.  I'm brand new to data-*.  Code example has been updated, but the alert still doesn't work (no alert displays).  I'm still lost on the syntax to access custom data attributes when the list element is stored in an array.  None of the online examples I've found take that into account.

Comment: You can't access it like that `griditem_0` is wrong. `result[0]` means `griditem_0`. 

`result[0]` equals `griditem_0` so we need to select it by `$('#'+result[0]).data('var1')`
Use it like this `alert($('#'+result[0]).data('var1'));`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the latest version of your comment.  When I run it like this, the alert at least runs, but it displays "undefined".

Comment: Wait, yes, this worked.  I found two errant angle brackets in the wrong place and once I fixed that, all was good.  Thanks for your help!